# Joomla insert article into component

Tags: joomla, insert, components, joomla-article

I would like to insert an article inside my component, does someone have an example on how to do that?

Article would be selected from backend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Back-End you will selected the article, the ID of article will be stored in a database in component params (`config.xml`) or custom component params table.

In you custom component

1. Store Article Id to variable
2. Query the database `#__content` table with Article ID
3. Display the article

For example

```
 //
 // Function for your model
 //
/**
 *
 * @return object 
 * 
 * Object will have following structure 
 * 
 * Field            Type    
 * ----------------------------------        
 * id               "int(11) unsigned"
 * title            varchar(255)
 * alias            varchar(255)
 * title_alias    varchar(255)
 * introtext        mediumtext
 * fulltext         mediumtext
 * state            tinyint(3)
 * sectionid        "int(11) unsigned"
 * mask             "int(11) unsigned"
 * catid            "int(11) unsigned"
 * created          datetime
 * created_by      "int(11) unsigned"
 * created_by_alias varchar(255)
 * modified         datetime
 * modified_by  "int(11) unsigned"
 * checked_out  "int(11) unsigned"
 * checked_out_time datetime
 * publish_up      datetime
 * publish_down  datetime
 * images           text
 * urls             text
 * attribs          text
 * version          "int(11) unsigned"
 * parentid         "int(11) unsigned"
 * ordering         int(11)
 * metakey          text
 * metadesc         text
 * access           "int(11) unsigned"
 * hits             "int(11) unsigned"
 * metadata         text
 */
 public function getMyArticle() {

        //  Get Component parameters (config.xml)
        $params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_mycomponent');

        //  Get Specific parameter
        $myArticleId = (int) $params->get('articleId', 0);

        //  Make sure parameter is set and is greater than zero
        if ($myArticleId > 0) {

            //  Build Query
            $query = "SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE id = $myArticleId";

            //  Load query into an object
            $db = JFactory::getDBO();
            $db->setQuery($query);
            return $db->loadObject();
        }

        //
        return null;
    }
```

---

To make pop-up select in the back end, edit your component's `config.xml`

add `addpath` to the `<params>` elements

```
<!-- Add the path to content elements -->
<params addpath="/administrator/components/com_content/elements">
   <!-- Add Select Article param -->
   <param name="articleId" type="article" default="0" label="Select Article" description="" />
```

You will also need to add `config` button to the toolbar on the component's default view

```
// Add this code in the display() method of the view
// @todo change com_mycomponent to your component's name
JToolBarHelper::preferences('com_mycomponent')
```

Comment: Thanks! :) it is working but going little bit further how to make popup select form to choose article in backend?

Comment: That is a good example however I would like to have it on same settings page not using params and preferences. Just simple form with button

Comment: you can do that. Better post a new question and I will answer the new question. With question goes way off the subject.